# NSUserDefaults - Saving Data For Use and Reuse - Erasing on each new startup?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults, uiapplicationdelegate

So for my game, I'm saving the "bool" value of whether or not the user has unlocked a powerup yet.  For this I am using NSUserDefaults.  I had originally followed a tutorial online about NSUserDefaults so let me put my code and explain (all of the following code is in the AppDelegate.m file):

(NOTE: "save" is a macro for: `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`)

```
powerups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dateKey"] == nil) {
    NSDictionary *appDefaults  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate date], @"dateKey", nil];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_1];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_2];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_3];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_4];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_5];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_6];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_7];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_8];
    [save setBool:NO forKey:POWER_9];

    [save setInteger:0 forKey:@"1HighScore"];
    [save setInteger:0 forKey:@"2HighScore"];
    [save setInteger:0 forKey:@"3HighScore"];
    [save setInteger:0 forKey:@"CumulativeScore"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"firstrun");
}
```

So in the above code, I am creating an array, which can be called from any class in my game, that stores all of the available powerups.  This "if" statement should only be called if this is the first time the game is played, because it creates all of the data values in the NSUserDefaults.  NOTE: I use a jailbroken iPhone and have inspected the created .plist file.  There seems to not be any value whatsoever called/with the value of "dateKey".  The tutorial said that this is the way to check if this is the first run, because if a date value doesn't exist then its the first run etc.  Logically, it made sense.

Now, the following code, populates the array given that the NSUserDefaults MUST exist, whether or not it was just "populated" or saved previously:

```
if([save boolForKey:POWER_1])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_1];
if([save boolForKey:POWER_2])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_2];
if([save boolForKey:POWER_3])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_3];
if([save boolForKey:POWER_4])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_4];
if([save boolForKey:POWER_5])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_5];
if([save boolForKey:POWER_6])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_6];
if([save boolForKey:POWER_7])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_7];
/*if([save boolForKey:POWER_8])
 [powerups addObject:POWER_8];*/
if([save boolForKey:POWER_9])
    [powerups addObject:POWER_9];
```

Now, it seems that on EVERY new run, the first "if" statement is YES, and all of the values are reset according that the first box of code...  which then causes the second box of code to act accordingly and have no array population because everything has been reset...

Could this have something to do with `registerDefaults`, is it even necessary to call or use, because I'm pretty sure this is the issue?

Thanks everyone, hopefully I was clear :)

rnc505

Comment: Are you testing this in the Simulator or on a device?

Comment: I'm testing it on both, but this occurs on a device.  I can't seem to properly test for this on the Simulator, but obviously, the device is the most important anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is registerDefaults is not written to disk per the Apple Docs

> The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you
>   need to call this method each time your application starts.

You have 2 options, 1) don't use registerDefaults and save your "date" like this

```
[save setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"dateKey"];
```

This will cause it to be written to disk and your code will work.

The more robust way would be to write all your powerups to registerDefaults and do away with the date. To ensure that the registerDefaults is called before anything else put it in the initialize method of your appDelegate, like this:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    NSMutableDictionary *defs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_!];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_2];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_3];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_4];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_5];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_6];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:POWER_7];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defs];
}
```

Comment: So what this does is every time it starts, calls this method. Then if if those values don't already exist, this creates them & if they already do, it is ignored.  But how does the data persist then? Through subsequent `[save setObject:[OBJECT] forKey:[KEY]]` and `[save sychronize]` calls?

Comment: The code in the initialize method above Registers defaults every time the app runs. That are used if there is no value for that key in NSUserDefaults. Then whenever a user gets a Power you would save it to disk calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:POWER_4];`